# How to install columnstore in MariaDB on Mac OS X with Homebrew

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

I would analyse time-series data using MariaDB ColumnStore but error encountered

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE forex;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> USE forex;
Database changed
MariaDB [forex]> CREATE TABLE gbpusd (
    ->     id INT, 
    ->     time DATETIME,
    ->     open DOUBLE,
    ->     high DOUBLE, 
    ->     low DOUBLE, 
    ->     close DOUBLE
    ->     ) engine=ColumnStore default character set=utf8;
ERROR 1286 (42000): Unknown storage engine 'ColumnStore'

brew install mariadb
```

After checking, I found the columnstore engine didn't exist.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                                          | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MyISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| SEQUENCE           | YES     | Generated tables filled with sequential values                                   | YES          | NO   | YES        |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables                        | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, foreign keys and encryption for tables | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| Aria               | YES     | Crash-safe tables with MyISAM heritage                                           | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please advise how to enable columnstore in MariaDB

Comment: What version of MariaDB?  You might need at least 10.1.19.

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB currently is a distinct download from regular vanilla which adds in the columnstore engine: https://mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb-ax

However we don't currently have a native Mac build so the simplest recommendation is to run this via docker in a vm: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-columnstore-docker-vagrant-and-windows-10-linux-setup-allows-for-ev/

Comment: Is it possible to compile from source code into a native Mac build?

Comment: Are there any new updates on columnstore engine for OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Answering Nelson Mok question, the columnstore engine couldn't be built under MacOS X now, since there are lots of linux|libboost specific code pieces throughout the code. I will try to fix it to compile it under Mac.